# Why doesn't my UIViewController class keep track of an NSArray instance variable

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, instance-variables

Hey, I am new to Objective-C 2.0 and Xcode, so forgive me if I am missing something elementary here. Anyways, I am trying to make my own UIViewController class called GameView to display a new view. To work the game I need to keep track of an NSArray that I want to load from a plist file. I have made a method 'loadGame' which I want to load the correct NSArray into an instance variable. However it appears that after the method executes the instance variable loses track of the array. Its easier if I just show you the code....

```
    @interface GameView : UIViewController {
        IBOutlet UIView *view 
        IBOutlet UILabel *label;
        NSArray *currentGame;
    }

    -(IBOutlet)next;
    -(void)loadDefault;
...
@implementation GameView
- (IBOutlet)next{
   int numElements = [currentGame count];
   int r = rand() % numElements;
   NSString *myString = [currentGame objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)r];
   [label setText: myString];
}
- (void)loadDefault {
    NSDictionary *games;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Games.plist"];
    games = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
    currentGame = [games objectForKey:@"Default"];
}
```

when loadDefault gets called, everything runs perfectly, but when I try to use the currentGame NSArray later in the method call to next, currentGame appears to be nil. I am also aware of the memory management issues with this code. Any help would be appreciated with this problem.

Comment: How do you know "everything runs perfectly"? Are you stepping through with the debugger and seeing that `games` and `currentGame` are being set correctly to non-nil values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-objectForKey:` doesn't return an object you own, you need to take ownership explicitly by retaining:

```
currentGame = [[games objectForKey:@"Default"] retain];
```

Or by using declared properties:

```
@interface GameView ()
@property (readwrite, retain) NSArray *currentGame;
@end

@implementation GameView
@synthesize currentGame;
// ...
- (void)loadDefault {
    // ...
    self.currentGame = [games objectForKey:@"Default"];
```

Comment: @Georg, how would it get set to `nil` though?  Unless the dictionary doesn't actually contain that object maybe?

Comment: @Carl: Good point, i overread the `nil` part. Chuck seems to have that covered though.

Comment: Brilliant! this appears to be exactly the problem. For future, what would you call a method such as <code> -objectForKey </code> which needs to be retained in order for you to take ownership? Thanks so much for your help Georg.

Comment: @Carl I misspoke when I said it got set to nil. Sorry about that.

Comment: @TaoStoner: You would call it a normal method. See the memory management guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: @Tao: As Chuck said, those aren't specially named, its the other way around. The guidelines say that you need to retain objects you don't own and that you own objects you create: *You “create” an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy”*

Answer (score 2):

I would be surprised if that code worked. Is `Games.plist` really at the top level of your bundle? It's not in your bundle's resources folder or in Documents or Application Support? I bet if you debug the method, you'll see that you're not correctly locating it.

Comment: It appears it does work even though Games.plist is ,in fact, in my resources folder. Thanks for the suggestion though.